# Java Servlet Insert MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, database, servlets, insert

I am attempting to insert records from an HTML form, into a MySQL database.  I have the HTML and Jquery down, but I have an issue with my Servlet.  I don't notice anything immediately wrong with it, but if I could get a point in the right direction I could get past my current spot. thanks

```
package com.david.servlets;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.sql.DataSource;


/**
 * Servlet implementation class myForm
 */

public class myForm extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException
        {
              //Get parameters
            String id = request.getParameter("ID");
            String fname = request.getParameter("FirstName");
            String lname = request.getParameter("LastName");


            //Get Connection
            try {
                Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Found a driver");
            Connection dbConnect = null;
            try {
                dbConnect = getConnection("localhost", 7001);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NamingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            System.out.println("Made a connection");


                //Create Query
            String query = "INSERT INTO test.customer (ID, FirstName, LastName) " + 
                    "VALUES (" + id + ", " + fname + ", " + lname + ")";
            PreparedStatement dbStatement = null;
            try {
                dbStatement = dbConnect.prepareStatement(query);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //Execute Query
            try {
                dbStatement.executeUpdate(query);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //close connection
            try {
                dbStatement.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                dbConnect.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }





public Connection getConnection(String server, int port)
        throws SQLException, NamingException {
    Context ctx = null;
    Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
    ht.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
    ht.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "t3://"+server+":"+port);
    ctx = new InitialContext(ht);
    DataSource ds = (javax.sql.DataSource) ctx.lookup ("localmysql");
    Connection conn =  ds.getConnection();
    //conn.setAutoCommit( true );
    return conn;
}    





}
```

Comment: Where does it fail? Stacktraces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing some single quotes around the `fname` and `lname` text fields:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO test.customer (ID, FirstName, LastName) " + 
           "VALUES (" + id + ", '" + fname + "', '" + lname + "')";
```

---

Note: The safest approach is to use the `PreparedStatement` placeholders rather than doing `String` concatenation. Not only will they protect against [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks, but they will also manage quotation characters.

```
String query = "INSERT INTO test.customer (ID, FirstName, LastName) VALUES (?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement dbStatement = dbConnect.prepareStatement(query);
dbStatement.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(id));
dbStatement.setString(2, fname);
dbStatement.setString(3, lname);
```

(`Id` fields are *typically* INTEGER types)

Comment: that worked thanks, also great suggestion on placeholders.

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine to me, however, you're using a PreparedStatement and not reaping any of its benefits by your query construction. For a solution, see my sample code, which follows:

```
   //Get Connection
    try {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Found a driver");
    Connection dbConnect = null;
    try {
        dbConnect = getConnection("localhost", 7001);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    System.out.println("Made a connection");


        //Create Query
    String query = "INSERT INTO test.customer (ID, FirstName, LastName) VALUES (?,?,?)";
    PreparedStatement dbStatement = null;
    try {
        dbStatement = dbConnect.prepareStatement(query);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // set parameters
    try {
        dbStatement.setString(1, ID);
        dbStatement.setString(2, fname);
        dbStatement.setString(3, lname);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //Execute Query
    try {
        if (dbStatement.executeUpdate(query) == 0) { 
            System.err.println("Nothing inserted"); 
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //close connection
    try {
        dbStatement.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        dbConnect.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: I will once I get more reputation, I just joined =)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the missing quotes as pointed by others I'd like to add that you're using `PreparedStatement` incorrectly. You're first preparing the Statement with

```
dbStatement = dbConnect.prepareStatement(query);
```

and then instead of executing the *already prepared* query

```
dbStatement.executeUpdate();
```

you're creating a ***new*** one unnecessarily and executing it with

```
dbStatement.executeUpdate(query);
```

This won't cause any errors or throw exceptions but is the WRONG way of doing JDBC.